# How to download Heroku app's automatically generated private SSL certificate

Tags: heroku, lets-encrypt

When using Heroku's Automated Certificate Manager is it possible to download the private certificate that was generated by the Let's Encrypt certificate authority?

Comment: have you tried using the `heroku run bash` command to start a shell on your instance? Once you do that, you could try poking around a bit for the cert files...

Comment: @duhaime Yes, a little. It's not in any environment variables. I also did a little searching in the filesystem. Since the app doesn't terminate SSL I don't believe it will be available within the instance, but I could be wrong.

Comment: did you generate the certs on that remote host (your Heroku instance)? Can you generate them from your local machine then upload from there? Then you'll have a copy you can use for other purposes if you must. What do you want to do with the certs?

Comment: I did not generate the certificates. I'm not sure we're on the same page regarding the Automated Certificate Manager, see this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) for details.

Comment: aha--can you use Let's Encrypt on your local machine then upload to your server? Let's Encrypt is pretty straightforward to run on a local server.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible